# How to access the TextBox in a SL3 AutoCompleteBox

Tags: silverlight, controls

I'd like to call the Select function on the TextBox used by the SL3 AutoCompleteBox.  What's a good way to access this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild("AutoCompleteBoxName", 0), 0) as TextBox

should give you the textbox